# Array as a function parameter instead separate variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need pass to a function (`jacobian()` in my case) a symbolic variable array is being creating dynamically. Say,

```
jacobian(handles{2}(t,y,paramlist),y)
```

where `paramlist=[var1, var2, var3, ..., varN]` has an arbitry size. All variables here are symbolic and have various names. MATLAB throw an error:

> Not enough input arguments.

Knowing number of parameters in the function definition one can pass all parameters separately. Say, for `n=3`:

```
 jacobian(handles{2}(t,y,paramlist(1),paramlist(2),paramlist(3)),y)
```

But what about the common case? It's a bad style of programming to write the function call for each fixed number of parameters. Is there a way to pass an array so as it would be treated as distinct variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `paramlist` to a cell array (using [`num2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html)) and then use `{:}` indexing to create a [comma separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) which you can then use this for indexing into `handles{2}`. This will make it such that each value of `paramlist` is passed as a separate subscript.

```
plistcell = num2cell(paramlist);
jacobian(handles{2}(t, y, plistcell{:}), y)
```